# Admob doesn't count clicks

Tags: android, admob

My Android app is in Market since three days and the number of impressions grow.. but number of clicks is 0.

I know some people has clicked in the advertisement but admob doesn't count this clicks.. (the code I think is correct.. the first day I tried a click and admob count it)

Somebody knows about it? any idea or suggestion?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Don't click your ads , any cheating will let you get banned !
Wait a bit and they'll be counted, If not delete the Site/App and get a new publisher id then update your app.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it takes a few days.  I frequently see changes in the past 2-3 days until the number stabilizes.  This can be caused by the "fill" option.